# Get status of bluetooth ON/OFF without using CBPeripheralManager

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, cbperipheral

I'm actually working on a swift3 project that it need to know if the bluetooth is activate or not on the device. I have reading lot of topics about this subject but none of them could help me to do it by another way than using the `centralManagerDidUpdateState`

Actually I have this code:

```
private func GetBluetoothInformation() {
    let options = [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:0]
    bluetoothPeripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: options)
}

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    var status: Bool = false

    switch peripheral.state {
    case .poweredOn:
        status = true
    default:
        status = false
    }
    m_session_chofer?.setIsBluetooth(status)
}
```

But by doing like this, I don't know if each time I call `GetBluetoothInformation` is going to update the status correctly or not.

Thank you for the help,

Comment: So you want to talk to Bluetooth, but not use the tools Apple provided for talking to Bluetooth?

Comment: If would like to know if exists another way to do it without using `CBPeripheralManager` but maybe by using `CBPeripheral`

Answer (score 0):

```
var btManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!) {
    println(__FUNCTION__)
    if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOn {
        println("Broadcast")
        btManager!.startAdvertising(_broadcastBeaconDict)
    } else if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOff {
        println("Stop")
        btManager!.stopAdvertising()
    } else if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.Unsupported {
        println("Unsupport")
    } else if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.Unauthorized {
        println("Not allow")
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm already doing with this method but my problem is do to it by another way